# Does Job Service stops after a reboot?

Tags: java, android, android-service, jobservice

I have initialized a job service using JobScheduler that runs periodically. I reschedule this service after a reboot. Does this service stops after the device reboots? Or is it still running?

Answer (score -2):

Job Service does not persist jobs，you can register a BroadcastReceiver with action BOOT_COMPLETED